# Update issue fields in JIRA

Tags: jira-rest-api

Hi I am using postman client for Chrome to run my rest api calls. I am trying to update issue in JIRA via rest API. I have referred to JIRA API also for updating an issue.

I am using PUT method to update an issue fields. Here is the syntax. 
PUT /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}

I am trying to update summary field like this.

{"update":{"summary":[{"set":"Bug in business logic"}]}}

But it is giving me the 400 bad request error.

and in the body its showing message "No content to map to Object due to end of input".

Please find the attached screenshot for more reference. Thanks in Advance.[Jira Update issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncUTF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman rest API client, add the json object to Body as in the below picture.

[image: Request Body]

- I added authorization as Basic Authorization and provided JIRA credentials.
- Note that the body should be raw and type should be JSON(application/json) instead of Text(default).
- Response for this PUT request is 204 when update is successful.

Here is [REST API Documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue-editIssue) for additional options.

Comment: Thanks man .... Worked .... I was previous submitting as a from-data I think ... when I put it in raw ... It worked